# Successful upload to AWS S3, but says bucket is still empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My function successfully uploads my image into S3, but I can't see the file anywhere.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let s3= new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {


    const promises = [];

        var message_body = JSON.parse(event.body);

        let encodedImage = message_body.base64;
        let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');

        var params = {
            "Bucket": "mybucket69-bucket",
            "Key": "testkey",
            "Body": decodedImage
        };

        console.log("function triggered. ");

        promises.push(s3.upload(params));

        await Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
            console.log('Success');
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, 'Success Uploading image');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null, 'Failed to upload image');
        });


};
```

Cloudwatch logs:

[image]

Checked bucketname countless times, made sure S3 bucket is public, now absolutely clueless to why the bucket is still empty

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the s3 bucket ?

Comment: about 100 times =)

Comment: Try using `putObject` method instead of `upload`?  `s3.putObject(params).promise()`

Comment: Tried that, it also times out my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `.promise()` method call.

```
promises.push(s3.upload(params).promise());
```

Without the `.promise()` call, the call to upload is not actually triggered. Read [this article](https://sarthakj178.com/handling-nodejs-promises-in-aws-lambda/) to understand the common mistakes while using NodeJS Promises in AWS Lambda.

BTW, if you are using async/await on NodeJS10.x and you actually have only one image in your logic, as indicated by the code, below is a much simplified and readable version of the same code :)

```
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
        const promises = [];
        var message_body = JSON.parse(event.body);

        let encodedImage = message_body.base64;
        let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');

        var params = {
            "Bucket": "mybucket69-bucket",
            "Key": "testkey",
            "Body": "someRandomString"
        };

        console.log("function triggered. ");

        try {
          const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
          console.log('Success');
          console.log(data);
          return;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err;
        }
};
```

Following is the output

```
START RequestId: 16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053 Version: $LATEST
2020-01-08T01:31:14.159Z        16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053    INFO    function triggered. 
2020-01-08T01:31:14.348Z        16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053    INFO    Success
2020-01-08T01:31:14.352Z        16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053    INFO    { ETag: '"7c6b8fecf5a9a9925d4115ee4f3c85a6"',
  Location: 'https://sarthakj178.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testkey',
  key: 'testkey',
  Key: 'testkey',
  Bucket: 'sarthakj178' }
END RequestId: 16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053
REPORT RequestId: 16b2982d-ac4f-18d6-e562-f6d81c973053  Init Duration: 1728.90 ms       Duration: 207.42 ms     Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB       Max Memory Used: 70 MB

null
```

And file gets created in S3

```
aws s3 ls s3://sarthakj178
2020-01-08 07:01:14         16 testkey
```

Comment: This probably means that the requests are going through but failing because of either large file sizes or poor network connectivity.  Can you try with a smaller image, or if possible some small txt file? Also are there too many files that you are trying to send via the promises array?

Comment: One image 8.9kb. There is only one item in the promise and the lambda function timeout is 1 minute.

Comment: I tried your code after removing the image decode logic, and sending 'someRandomText' as the 'Body' in the upload call(). Seems to work fine for me. Can you try the same? Just to identify whether the problem is with images or with the s3 async call.

Comment: I changed ```"Body": decodedImage``` to ```"Body": 'testString1'``` and my function is timing out when I add the ```.promise()```. I'm currently using ```Node.js 10.x``` if that matters or not. Tried ```8.10``` and ```12.x``` both still do not work with the ```.promise```

Comment: Very weird :)
BTW, if you are using async/await in Node10 and you actually have only one image to process, I will update my answer to include a much simplified version of your code. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: yeah your code is also giving me a timeout, not sure why. Can you post your cloudwatch logs?

Comment: I've added the output logs in my answer. BTW, I am running the lambda locally using aws sam cli.

Comment: ....I just figured out the problem after wasting so much time. My Lambda function had a VPC that didn't grant access to S3...omg. Now the function is not timing out, and the upload finally is working. I wish it would show an error, but none